# Max number of PHP CLI processes

Tags: php

I have a PHP script that is called by an external process when certain events happen, like when an email arrives. So if during a period of time, the triggering event happens multiple times, the script is invoked multiple times as well.

**What's the limit on max number of instances of the script running concurrently? How would I go about loosening the limit?**

I have read about various pieces of info on max number of concurrent connections in the context of Apache/PHP, but I think the CLI context works differently.

My environment is Ubuntu 16.04LTS/PHP 7.0.

Thanks!

Comment: It all depends on how much ram and cpu you have

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Linux, the max number of processes is determined by several factors:

```
cat /proc/sys/kernel/pid_max
```

This will show the maximum PID value + 1 (i.e. the highest value PID is one less than this value).  When you hit this value, the kernel wraps around.  Note that the first 300 are reserved.  The default value is 32768, so the maximum number of PIDs is 32767 - 300 = 32467.

This will show you the maximum number of processes that your user account can run:

```
ulimit -u
```

So if you're running all of your processes as a single user, and this number is less than the pid_max value, then this may be your upper limit.

These values can be adjusted (particularly on 64-bit systems), but they're unlikely to be your real-world upper limit.  In most cases, the maximum number of processes is going to be based on your hardware resources.  And I suspect that if you try to run anywhere near 32,000 PHP CLI instances, you'll run out of RAM far earlier than you'll run out of available process space.

The maximum number of processes is going to depend on what your script does; particularly, how much CPU and RAM it uses.  Your best bet is to kick off a script that runs X number of your CLI processes for an extended period of time, then watch the load on your system.  Start with 10.. if the load is negligible, bump it to 100.  Then continue that process until you have a noticeable load.  Find out what your max load is, then do the match to figure out what your max number of processes is.

Comment: In case he want to increse pid values sysctl -w kernel.pid_max=xxxxxxx